# Why did find with -delete erase the files in my /save/ directory when find without delete was not able to locate them?

Tags: find

I want to delete all the files in the current directory tree, except those in `save`. I ran this command:

```
 find . \( -name save -prune \) -o -type f -ls | grep /save/
```

and it found none. But when I ran this command:

```
 find . \( -name save -prune \) -o -type f -delete
```

All those files in /save/ were gone. What am I missing?

Comment: Ouch ... I learned something today (thanks to you). And I recommend a simple `mv save/  ../some/safer/location` prior to such a "generic" delete command (... but of course, prior to your post I'd have done the same check and ran into the same trouble!). Now go find a good "undelete" for the filesystem the files were on ^^

Comment: My pain is your prevention.

Comment: 1000 thanks to you. Code (often?) works in mysterious ways...

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87258/delete-all-files-except-in-a-certain-subdirectory-with-find

Comment: @lesmana I upvoted your answer there. sadly, my version of find doesn't give me such a nice warning :(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`-delete` implies `-depth` that doesn't work with `-prune` (`-depth` starts with the leaves). There's a warning about that in the manual of the GNU version (`-delete` is a FreeBSD extension now also supported by GNU `find` and a few other implementations).

```
info -- find -delete
```

> The use of the '-delete' action on the command line automatically
> turns on the '-depth' option (*note find Expressions::).  This can
> be surprising if you were previously just testing with '-print', so
> it is usually best to remember to use '-depth' explicitly.

```
info -- find -prune
```

> Because '-delete' implies '-depth', using '-prune' in combination
> with '-delete' may well result in the deletion of more files than
> you intended.

Here, you've got the option of either using `rm` instead:

```
find . -name save -prune -o -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

(potentially [unsafe](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec.html#Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec) if there are directory writeable by others in there, as one could make you delete files outside the current directory tree by replacing directories with symlinks while you run that command).

A safer alternative:

```
find . -name save -prune -o -type f -execdir rm -f -- {} \;
```

That doesn't have the problem mentioned above but means running one `rm` per file. The `--` is necessary for the FreeBSD implementation, not the GNU one that prefixes file names with `./`.

Alternatively, as suggested by Costas:

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name save ! -path '*/save/*' -type f -delete
```

(but that still needlessly descends into `save` directories)

The `LC_ALL=C` is there so `*` matches any sequence of bytes (even those that don't form valid characters in the current locale). Note that it will affect the language of error messages (English instead of the language of the user).

Comment: What's the security issue here with `rm`?

Comment: @jrw32982, see edit with link to the GNU find manual