# Remove certain types of files except in a folder

Tags: bash, shell, find, rm

I have a command in my `makefile` for `clean`:

```
rm -rf */*.o */*.cmo */*.cmi */*.cmx */*.cma */*.cmxa */*.annot
```

Now I would like to write a `cleanpartial` that removes these files except those in the folder `frontend/` and the folder `frontend/gen/`.

Does anyone know how to write this command properly?

Comment: Do you mean that matching files *directly* within `frontend` should be left alone, but matching files in e.g. `frontend/somedir` should be deleted?  What about matching files in `frontend/gen/somedir`?  (The [answer I gave](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275034/135943) simply skips everything within `frontend` and all of its subdirectories, that being the simplest interpretation.)

Comment: The above is a more specific case of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87258/135943 as it involves pattern matching as well as excluding a directory; not quite a duplicate but closely related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `find` for this.

You can safely test with the following command:

```
find . \( -name frontend -prune \) -o -type f \( -name \*.o -o -name '*.cm[oixa]' -o -name \*.cmxa -o -name \*.annot \) -print
```

Once you're happy with the list of files that gets printed, run the real command to delete the lot of them:

```
find . \( -name frontend -prune \) -o -type f \( -name \*.o -o -name '*.cm[oixa]' -o -name \*.cmxa -o -name \*.annot \) -exec rm -f {} +
```